# How can this SCSS still be used in this Codesandbox even it's not used by the React Component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sass

I have a question about SCSS in this [GitHub](https://github.com/sorioinc/react-file-viewer). I learn this and find one thing confusing.

The repo is showing different filetypes like jpg, docx or pdf.

I created a [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-file-viewer-master-mzijq?file=/src/components/file-viewer.jsx) of this repo to ask questions about it.

Opening that Codesandbox you see the file-viewer.jsx in the viewer and it loads `import '../styles/main.scss';` that contains;

```
.pg-viewer-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;

  .pg-viewer {
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    flex-grow: 2;

    .pg-driver-view {
      margin: auto;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;

      .loading {
        position: relative;
      }
```

I can see in the file-viewer.jsx `render()` that it uses the SCSS `.pg-viewer-wrapper` and children.

When I select in the [App.js](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-file-viewer-master-mzijq?file=/src/App.js:37-354) to show a docx file like this;

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import FileViewer from "./components/file-viewer";
import docx from "../example_files/SampleSpec.docx";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <FileViewer fileType="docx" filePath={docx} />,
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

Then it loads the docx-viewer.jsx that have the `import '../../styles/docx.scss';` SCSS. Viewing this SCSS it looks like this;

```
.pg-viewer-wrapper {
  overflow-y: scroll;

  #docx {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  
  .document-container {
    padding: 30px;
    width: 700px;
    background: white;
    margin: auto;
  }

  html,
  bodyaddress,
  blockquote,
  body,
  dd,
  div,
  dl,
  dt,
  fieldset,
  form,
  frame,
  frameset,
  h1,
  h2,
  h3,
  h4,
  h5,
  h6,
  noframes,
  ol,
  p,
  ul,
  center,
  dir,
  hr,
  menu,
  pre {
    display: block;
    unicode-bidi: embed;
  }
  li {
    display: list-item;
    list-style-type: disc;
  }
  head {
    display: none
  }
  table {
    display: table
  }
  img {
    width: 100%
  }
  tr {
    display: table-row
  }
  thead {
    display: table-header-group
  }
  tbody {
    display: table-row-group
  }
  tfoot {
    display: table-footer-group
  }
  col {
    display: table-column
  }
  colgroup {
    display: table-column-group
  }
  th {
    display: table-cell
  }
  td {
    display: table-cell;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 0.2em 0.5em;
  }
  caption {
    display: table-caption
  }
  th {
    font-weight: bolder;
    text-align: center;
  }
  caption {
    text-align: center
  }
  body {
    margin: 8px
  }
  h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
    margin: .67em 0;
  }
  h2 {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    margin: .75em 0;
  }
  h3 {
    font-size: 1.17em;
    margin: .83em 0;
  }
  h4,
  p,
  blockquote,
  ul,
  fieldset,
  form,
  ol,
  dl,
  dir,
  menu {
    margin: 1.12em 0
  }
  h5 {
    font-size: .83em;
    margin: 1.5em 0;
  }
  h6 {
    font-size: .75em;
    margin: 1.67em 0;
  }
  h1,
  h2,
  h3,
  h4,
  h5,
  h6,
  b,
  strong {
    font-weight: bolder
  }
  blockquote {
    margin-left: 40px;
    margin-right: 40px;
  }
  i,
  cite,
  em,
  var,
  address {
    font-style: italic
  }
  pre,
  tt,
  code,
  kbd,
  samp {
    font-family: monospace
  }
  pre {
    white-space: pre
  }
  button,
  textarea,
  input,
  select {
    display: inline-block
  }
  big {
    font-size: 1.17em
  }
  small,
  sub,
  sup {
    font-size: .83em
  }
  sub {
    vertical-align: sub
  }
  sup {
    vertical-align: super
  }
  table {
    border-spacing: 2px
  }
  thead,
  tbody,
  tfoot {
    vertical-align: middle
  }
  td,
  th,
  tr {
    vertical-align: inherit
  }
  s,
  strike,
  del {
    text-decoration: line-through
  }
  hr {
    border: 1px inset
  }
  ol,
  ul,
  dir,
  menu,
  dd {
    margin-left: 40px
  }
  ol {
    list-style-type: decimal
  }
  ol ul, ol ul,
  ul ol, ul ol,
  ul ul, ul ul,
  ol ol, ol ol {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
  u,
  ins {
    text-decoration: underline
  }
  br:before {
    content: "\A";
    white-space: pre-line;
  }
  center {
    text-align: center
  }
  :link,
  :visited {
    text-decoration: underline
  }
  :focus {
    outline: thin dotted invert
  }
  /* Begin bidirectionality settings (do not change) */
  BDO[DIR="ltr"] {
    direction: ltr;
    unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
  }
  BDO[DIR="rtl"] {
    direction: rtl;
    unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
  }
  *[DIR="ltr"] {
    direction: ltr;
    unicode-bidi: embed;
  }
  *[DIR="rtl"] {
    direction: rtl;
    unicode-bidi: embed;
  }
  @media print {
    h1 {
      page-break-before: always
    }
    h1,
    h2,
    h3,
    h4,
    h5,
    h6 {
      page-break-after: avoid
    }
    ul,
    ol,
    dl {
      page-break-before: avoid
    }
  }
}
```

As you see it also have the `.pg-viewer-wrapper {..`.

My question is since docx-viewer.jsx don't have in its `render()..` any references to the `.pg-viewer-wrapper {..` so how can it still be used in the docx-viewer.jsx? I just learn this so probably its basic stuff :)

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  Are you asking why no elements match the CSS selector `.pg-viewer-wrapper`?

Comment: @Thanks the docx-viewer.jsx is using the ` .pg-viewer-wrapper {...` selector from the `import '../../styles/docx.scss';` but in the code in docx-viewer.jsx `render..` it does not use the selector but still i see the SCSS is applied

Comment: @HoldOffHunger, In the docx-viewer.jsx how can the docx.scss be applied??. The render dont have any selector for docx.scss??

Answer (score 0):

The `.pg-viewer-wrapper` is applied in the `<FileViewer ... >`, which is the file [file-viewer.jsx](https://github.com/sorioinc/react-file-viewer/blob/master/src/components/file-viewer.jsx), and which imports and wraps the file [docx-viewer.jsx](https://github.com/sorioinc/react-file-viewer/blob/master/src/components/drivers/docx-viewer.jsx).

`file-viewer.jsx` renders:

```
render() {
  const Driver = this.getDriver(this.props);
  return (
    <div className="pg-viewer-wrapper">
      <div className="pg-viewer" id="pg-viewer">
        <Driver ... />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The resulting HTML including the `Driver` would be like:

```
<div className="pg-viewer-wrapper">
  <div className="pg-viewer" id="pg-viewer">
    <div id="docx">
      <div class="document-container">
        ... the generated HTML ...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But docx-viewer.jsx also have docx.scss that contains .pg-viewer-wrapper that is applied even the docx-viewer.jsx dont have in its render any selector for it, how does that work?? –

Comment: `docx-viewer.jsx` probably imports the `docx.scss` only for applying the style `#docx { ... }` to `id="docx"`. `.pg-viewer-wrapper` is not used in `docx-viewer.jsx`.

Comment: I have added an example.

Comment: Thanks Test in the [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-file-viewer-master-mzijq?file=/src/styles/docx.scss:83-130)  and edit/remove some SCSS like [this](https://snipboard.io/eGMYKD.jpg) and you see docx-viewer.jsx is using it all even in the render it's not using `.pg-viewer-wrapper`

Comment: how do you think that docx-viewer.jsx is using .pg-viewer-wrapper ? You are showing the scss file, but that doesn't say anything about which of the styles are used, even if the scss file is imported somewhere. My point is, that docx-viewer.jsx is not using .pg-viewer-wrapper, file-viewer.jsx is using .pg-viewer-wrapper.

Comment: But docx-viewer.jsx is using `.pg-viewer-wrapper` in  docx.scss that's why I created this question to ask how it could do that. Just test in my [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-file-viewer-master-mzijq?file=/src/components/file-viewer.jsx) and edit the docx.scss you will see that the word docx document is changing

Comment: Ah, you mean the style `.pg-viewer-wrapper .document-container`. `.document-container` is added in the line `docEl.className = 'document-container'` in `docx-viewer.jsx`. `.pg-viewer-wrapper` is applied in `file-viewer.jsx`, which is a parent of `DocxViewer`. Together that style becomes `.pg-viewer-wrapper .document-container`. (I also added `document-container` to my example.)

Comment: it doesn't matter in which file you import the SCSS, you could also import all of them inside of App.js

Comment: Thanks. What is confusing is that both file-viewer.jsx and docx-viewer.jsx both have scss files and in both there is `.pg-viewer-wrapper` - I was thinking that docx-viewer.jsx could not use the `.pg-viewer-wrapper`. I think then now that this type of coding must be bad?????

Comment: You can understand `.pg-viewer-wrapper` inside the scss files as an "identifier", so it says "apply a style to the element which has the class .pg-viewer-wrapper". So it is ok to use the same identifier in multiple files to refer to the same element... but CSS is indeed a little weird sometimes, and some awkward redundancy is unavoidable. Actually, SCSS is already meant to solve some of this weirdness.

Comment: I think that it should not be allowed that docx-viewer.jsx inheriting  `.pg-viewer-wrapper` since it's parent is doing that. This feels like a Dependency breach